# hive query as a string to use load data

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have an Hive table to store some csv path in purpose of loading them.

I would like to use my hive  table  when I am loading some data.

For example:-

`LOAD DATA INPATH (select path from my_path_table)  OVERWRITE INTO TABLE my_result_table`

Is it possible to do it with Hive ?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that?

Answer (score -1):

You can provide the path hard coded in your query.

Another option is, You can create an external table by providing the same location. You don'n need to run the overwrite command in this case. Whatever data would be available at HDFS location, you can directly view from this table.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_result_table(col string)
LOCATION 'hdfs location'
```

I hope, This will help you.

---

May be I interpreted question in wrong way:

As per my understanding now, you have paths available in you my_path_table and you want to insert those paths into final table.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my_result_table select path from my_path_table;
```

Thanks,
Manu